# Bootstrap Overlay image not responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this CSS Code to make an image overlay on top of a slider in bootstrap but when resizing down the image is not responsive:

```
.overlay {
background: url(../img/bocSlider.png) top left no-repeat;
position: absolute; 
background-position: center;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
pointer-events: none;
  }
     @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
      .overlay{

         width:50%;
        height:50%;
  }    
 }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .overlay{

  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  }

  }
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .overlay{
   width:50%;
  height:50%;

  }
}
```

Below is the HTML for the slider that I am using:

```html
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="overlay" class="img-responsive"></div>
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="/img/Bar.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Outside.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Table_1.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/img/Tables_2.jpg" class="fill">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
      </a>  
    </div>
```

Could someone please help me fix this issue?

Image is a .png

Comment: First check whether you have included the meta View-port tag, else your media queries wont work.
Use max-width instead of width,
Also set height to auto, else your img would lose its proportion,
By this way you max-width would alway be proportion to its device width..

Comment: @WisdmLabs if I set height to auto in the .overlay the image doesn't even appear...-

Comment: @WisdmLabs I have the meta viewoporttag in my doc, this is just a snippit of the site I'm working on.. As I said before if i use anything other than height and width the image doesn't appear

Comment: Based on the images provided by you in the below comments,
What you actually require is the overlay div to be center aligned and rescale it down in size too,
set following style to your .overlay:-  display:inline-block; margin: 0 auto;
Hence when your overlay hits media query and your size is reduce to 75% width your overlay would be aligned as desired....

Answer (score 1):

You can use background color instead of overlay image.
just write

`background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In you css add background size property

```
.overlay {
background: url(../img/bocSlider.png) top left no-repeat;
position: absolute; 
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
pointer-events: none;
  }
```

You are adding class in wrong way and in bootstrap img-responsive applies to img tag,

```
<div class="overlay" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="overlay img-responsive"></div>
```

For your code remove img-responsive

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry! Was just trying that class thing out! Didnt realise I put it in If I add this in background-size:100%, the image is Way too big, https://i.gyazo.com/60146ca3d761810515cfc43c48538caf.jpg The desired size would be at 50% (https://i.gyazo.com/edf74e4742c3d693182a723203a680bd.jpg) but when I scale down this happens https://i.gyazo.com/be7a228415d5e56ecbfd4b8842e8ce4a.png

Comment: Try background-size: cover; instead of background-size: 100%;

Comment: Still the same as 100% way to big & Still doesn't scale down properly

Comment: Try background-size: contain 100%;